# How to convert csv to nested arrays in json using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, representation

I am trying to use csv file to read data and convert them into nested array using python.

my column values of csv are

```
"hallticket_Number ","student_name","gender","course_name","university_course_code ","university_college_code","caste","course_year","semester_yearly_exams","subject_name1","subject_code1","marks_or_grade_points_obtained1","maximum_marks_or_grade_points1","pass_mark1","no_of_credits1","pass_fail_absent1","subject_name2","subject_code2","marks_or_grade_points_obtained2","maximum_marks_or_grade_points2","no_of_credits2","pass_fail_absent2" ,"subject_name3","subject_code3",  "marks_or_grade_points_obtained3","maximum_marks_or_grade_points3","no_of_credits3", "pass_fail_absent3" ,"subject_name4" ,"subject_code4"  ,"marks_or_grade_points_obtained4","maximum_marks_or_grade_points4","no_of_credits4" , "pass_fail_absent4" ,"subject_code5",  "marks_or_grade_points_obtained5" ,"maximum_marks_or_grade_points5","no_of_credits5","pass_fail_absent5","subject_name6","marks_or_grade_points_obtained6","maximum_marks_or_grade_points6", "no_of_credits6","pass_fail_absent","final_result_pass_fail","marks_or_sgpa_
```

The output i need in JSON is

```
{
  "hallticket_": 22342,
  "student_name": "abc",
  "gender": "m",
 "course_name":" fgd",
"course_code":52,
"college_code ":521,
"caste":"open",
"year":55,
"exam":"s1",



  "subject": [ {
"subject_name1":"hh",
"subject_code1":52,
"marks_or_grade_points_obtained1":85,
"maximum_marks_or_grade_points1":50,
"pass_mark1":52,
"no_of_credits1":85,
    "pass_fail_absent1":"pass"},]



  "subject": [ {
"subject_name2":"hh",
"subject_code2":52,
"marks_or_grade_points_obtained2":85,
"maximum_marks_or_grade_points2":50,
"pass_mark2":52,
"no_of_credits2":85,
    "pass_fail_absent2":"pass"},]



  "subject": [ {
"subject_name3":"hh",
"subject_code3":52,
"marks_or_grade_points_obtained3":85,
"maximum_marks_or_grade_points3":50,
"pass_mark3":52,
"no_of_credits3":85,
    "pass_fail_absent3":"pass"},]





  "subject": [ {
"subject_name4":"hh",
"subject_code4":52,
"marks_or_grade_points_obtained4":85,
"maximum_marks_or_grade_points4":50,
"pass_mark4":52,
"no_of_credits4":85,
    "pass_fail_absent4":"pass"},]



  "subject": [ {
"subject_name5":"hh",
"subject_code5":52,
"marks_or_grade_points_obtained5":85,
"maximum_marks_or_grade_points5":50,
"pass_mark5":52,
"no_of_credits5":85,
    "pass_fail_absent5":"pass"},]



"subject": [ {
"subject_name6":"hh",
"subject_code6":52,
"marks_or_grade_points_obtained6":85,
"maximum_marks_or_grade_points6":50,
"pass_mark6":52,
"no_of_credits6":85,
    "pass_fail_absent6":"pass"},]


"final_result_pass_fail":"pass",
" marks_or_sgpa_obtained":"8.00",
"maximum_marks_sgpa":"10",
"total_credits":"135"



}
```

Comment: You have to write your own parser for this. What have you tried?

Comment: reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import json

# Open the CSV
f = open('data.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
# Parse the CSV into JSON
out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])
print(out)
```

Hopefully this will work as your expectations!

Comment: but i need subject in array